# what slash in json in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Rest Spring :
how to understand that what has happened in output?

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/persons", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findAll() {

        try {
            List<Person> listModel = null;

            listModel = personService.findAll();
            Gson gson = new Gson();

            System.out.println(gson.toJson(listModel));

            return gson.toJson(listModel);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }

    }
}
```

out put:

```
[{"ID":1,"firstName":"j","lastName":"s","nationalCode":1-86,"gender":"male","fatherName":"sss","deleted":"0"}]
```

but in browser is (slash):

```
"[{\"ID\":1,\"firstName\":\"j\",\"lastName\":\"s\",\"nationalCode\":1-86,\"gender\":\"male\",\"fatherName\":\"sss\",\"deleted\":\"0\"}]"
```

What is and how it can be solved

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong. This is escaping double quotes in your json string. Another way to look at it is that there are double quotes within your string and this is a way to convey it.

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character so you can include `"` in strings